# Importing Vue Components with Webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have a hello world Vue app setup with Webpack and have the initial App component working and mounted to body. Although within that App component I can't figure out how to use more components I made.

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'
    
new Vue({ 
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

`app.vue`

```vue
<template>
  <div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'Hello World'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have tried

```js
import TopBar from './top-bar.vue'
```

In both main.js and the script section of app.vue then tried using

```vue
<top-bar></top-bar>
```

without luck.

I think I'm missing how to register the component properly, such as in the Vue docs it does:

```js
Vue.component('top-bar', TopBar)
```

But I think when using webpack with vue-loader I need to do something different.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can register it globally like you showed, or if you want to register it locally for use in a single component you need to add it to the `components` object of the Vue instance:

```vue
<template>
  <top-bar></top-bar>
  <div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import TopBar from './top-bar.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    TopBar
  },
  data () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can give it a suitable name in the components object as shown bellow

```vue
<template>
  <nav-bar></nav-bar>
</template>

<script>
import TopBar from './TopBar.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'nav-bar': TopBar
  }
}
</script>
```