# Import vue component using web pack

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm really new to Vue.js and are wondering how to import a vue component. I have two components. The first is Index.js and the second being Ch.js. Index.js displays perfectly. I import and Ch.js and nothing appears. Both Index and Ch contain the same code for a Chart.js graph that I built.

How can I get Ch.js to render like Index.js?

index.vue

```
<template>
  <!-- <index></index> -->
  <ch></ch>
</template>

<script>
  import Index from '../components/index'
  import Ch from '../components/ch'
</script>
```

Ch.js

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Line.extend({
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: ["data", "options"],
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['2:00pm', '2:15pm', '2:30pm', '2:45pm', '2:50pm'],
      datasets: [{
        borderColor: "#57C1E8",
        pointBackgroundColor: '#57C1E8',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0)',
        showTooltip: false,
        data: [5, 8, 3, 2, 3, 6, 3],
      }, {
        borderColor: "#82bc00",
        pointBackgroundColor: '#82bc00',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0)',
        showTooltip: false,
        data: [3, 4, 8, 6, 10, 2, 1]
      }, {
        borderColor: "#f7a800",
        pointBackgroundColor: '#f7a800',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0)',
        data: [8, 6, 10, 15, 6, 2, 3]
      }]
    }, {
      elements: {
        line: { tension: 0  },
        point: { radius: 0  }
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: { display: false },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: "rgba(0,0,0, 0.2)",
            drawBorder: false,
          },
          ticks: { display: false }
        }],
        xAxes: [ {
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0,0,0, 0.2)",
            borderDash: [10, 5],
            display: true,
            drawBorder: false
          }
        }]
      }
    })
  }
})
```

[I've taken a look at this thread, but it didn't work/help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416970/importing-vue-compoents-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your `index.vue`'s script tag should include the content of your `components/index.js` file.
- Your index component should import the `Ch` component and use it in it's Vue definition
- Your index template should have a single DOM element wrapping all else

---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ch></ch>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Ch from '../components/ch';

  export default {
    // your index component vue here

    components: { Ch }

  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks deefour. Just figured that out on my own actually. Silly mistake on my part lol. I'll mark your comment as being the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  components: { Index, Ch }
}
```

Must be called in order to grab the component(s).