# VueJs view in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I wonder how can i get my page parts such as `sidebar` or `header` with Vue way?

currently I get them like `@include('admin.parts.header')` which is blade template, but is it possible i move them to `components (header.vue)` and get them with vue way like `<router-view name="header"></router-view>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Vue Components with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416970/importing-vue-components-with-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to import via @include. You need to import vue components only with vue, blade with blade.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to have div with id around my sidebar.vue (eg) template and call that id instead of  in my main component.